# Data in UITableView doesn't refresh in a specific case

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

It looks very strange as data in my tableView mostly is refreshed, but in a specific, but indeed very important case, it won't be refreshed.

So, I have 2 structures:

```
struct ItemsStructure {
    var itemId: Int
    var code: String
    var externalId: Int
    var manufactureName: String
    var price: Double
    var weight: Int
}
```

and the structure that contain's the first one:

```
struct ListStructure {
    var listId: Int
    var createdDate: Date
    var wasSent: Bool
    var items: [ItemsStructure]
}
```

Also I have 2 `UITableViewController`s. The first shows the array of ListStructure and the second: the contents of a particular selected List. Also, the second controller allows to delete Items in the List. And the problem is what I have for example a List with 3 Items. While I delete first and the second Item from the List and return to the first controller, I might see the result: the List contain less Items. But, deletion of the last Item looks different. Returning to the first tableView I still see that the List contains one Item, whereas it is empty. And only closing and re-opening of the application will show me the empty List (without any Items).

Yes, I've read about putting of `tableView.reloadData()` into the `DispatchQueue.main.async` but the result is the same as I call `tableView.reloadData()` without DispatchQueue.

Any manupulation with Items in the List are performed via delegates. And printing of the List shows that the List do empty.

Bellow is code of the ListViewController

```
class ListsViewController: UIViewController {
    var dataSource: ListViewDataSource!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowParticularItem" {
            if let listVC = segue.destination as? ParticularListViewController {
                let listNumberToPass = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
                let listToPass = dataSource.stateController.lists[listNumberToPass]
                listVC.listNumber = listNumberToPass
                listVC.list = listToPass
                listVC.delegate = dataSource.self
            }
        }
    }
}

protocol ParticularListViewControllerDelegate: class {
func delete(listNumber: Int, itemNumber: Int)
```

}

```
class ParticularListViewController: UITableViewController {
var listNumber: Int!
var list: ListStructure!
weak var delegate: ParticularListViewControllerDelegate?


@IBOutlet weak var creationTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sentStatusLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weightLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var totalCostLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sentListButtonOutlet: UIButton!
@IBAction func sentListButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sentList()
    markListAsSent()
    refreshData()
}

func refreshData(){
    self.creationTimeLabel.text = "The list was created at \(list.createdDate)"
    if list.wasSent {
        self.sentStatusLabel.text = "The list has been already sent"
        self.sentListButtonOutlet.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        self.sentStatusLabel.text = "The list hasn't been sent yet"
        self.sentListButtonOutlet.isEnabled = true
    }
    let totalWeight: Int = list.items.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.weight})
    self.weightLabel.text = "The list contains \(list.items.count) items with total weight \(totalWeight) gramms"
    self.totalCostLabel.text = "The total cost is: \(list.totalCost) ₽"
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refreshData()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    refreshData()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return list.items.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ParticularListTableViewCell
    let index = indexPath.row
    cell.item = list.items[index]

    return cell
}

func delete(itemNumber: Int){
    delegate?.delete(listNumber: listNumber, itemNumber: itemNumber)
    self.refreshData()
}
```

}

```
extension ListViewDataSource: ParticularListViewControllerDelegate {
func delete(listNumber: Int, itemNumber: Int) {
    stateController.delete(fromList: listNumber, itemNumber: itemNumber)
}
```

}

```
class ListViewDataSource: NSObject{
var stateController: StateController

init(stateController: StateController) {
    self.stateController = stateController
}
```

}

```
extension ListViewDataSource: UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stateController.lists.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListsCell", for: indexPath) as! ListsTableViewCell
    let index = indexPath.row
    let listToPass = stateController.lists[index]
    cell.listToShow = ListsTableViewCell.ListModel(model: listToPass)

    return cell
}
```

}

```
class StateController{
fileprivate let storageController: StorageController
fileprivate(set) var lists: [ListStructure]
fileprivate let context: NSManagedObjectContext

init(storageController: StorageController, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    self.storageController = storageController
    self.context = context
    self.lists = storageController.fetchAllLists(inContext: context)
}
```

}

and as I've said before printing inside the ListViewController.ViewWillAppear shows that the stateController.lists.Items is empty

Comment: Show the code where you are deleting; remember that structs and arrays are value types in Swift

Comment: Please edit your question to include the additional code. It is very difficult to read in comments

Answer (score 0):

As Array and Structs are value types , the changes that you do to the copy would not get reflected. After updating the Datasource make sure to update the data source of source view controller as well. You might need to implement delegate for this. Other way would be to have common data source via singleton, but I would not suggest that.

Comment: Hi! Thank you and sorry for a late response. The dataSourse for the ListsViewController is ListsViewDataSource.listsArray and it is being updated via delegate function `delete` in the `extention ListViewDataSource: ParticularListViewControllerDelegate`.

Comment: And do I understand you correct what any way the problem is in value types of array? As the `UITableView` is being well refreshed until the internal array is not empty. And only as soon as the internal array takes empty, the `UITableView` stops refreshing.

Comment: All agreed. Your tableView.dataSoure = dataSource and not self. i.e. ListsViewController. Put a breakpoint at numberOfRows in Datasource. There you might realise that the number that you are returning is still 1. Please check that.

Comment: Have just checked. Nope: there is 0 items.  http://www.homber.ru/i/emptyItems.png

Comment: have you implemented numberOfRows for the tableView under discussion? Put a break point there and check what you are retuning.

Comment: I also have rewritten the code to use the only stataController which is passed to the dataSource.

Comment: yes. I've just put into the initial post the `extension ListViewDataSource: UITableViewDataSource` the breakpoint was at the line `return stateController.lists.count`